# Google One Tap descriptions

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-one-tap

We integrated Google One Tap on our site and have had some amazing results. Had a question on further integration:

When One Tap loads on the right hand side, is there a way to know its width/height? We want to display a 'Why sign up?' UI element below it, so our users know the value of a registration.

Answer (score 0):

There are two container elements, the one used to load One Tap using HTML on a page:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
     data-callback="YOUR_CALLBACK_HANDLER">
</div>
```

A second, dynamic container renders the prompt within an iframe:

```
<div id="credential_picker_container" 
     style="position: fixed; z-index: 9999; height: 183px;">

  <iframe src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/iframe/select?LOTS_OF REDACTED_URL_PARAMETERS" 
    title="Sign in with Google Dialog" 
    style="height: 183px; width: 391px; overflow: hidden;">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

and `height` and `width` are available for the container.

You may also use `data-prompt_parent_id` with a container ID of your choosing ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-prompt_parent_id)) if that's helpful in managing position and size of elements on the page.

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful.